# How to create a view that shows Variations type, Vocab name, terms values?

Tags: views

**Product variation type view**

Hello Drupal community,

I'm trying to create a view which shows **product variation type**, **attribute name** (drupal vocab name), **attributes value** (drupal terms name) of that variantion type.

**EXAMPLE:**

> Variantion type, Attribute name, Attribute value
>
> Variations type, Vocab name, terms values
>
> Audio Video , Colour , Black

So far I managed to get Terms name and Vocabulary names but how to relate them to Product Variation type?

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thank you
Darius

Comment: how is this data related? are they all fields on the same content type? are they different content types - and if so are you using entity reference or similar? More information on the data structure is needed...

Comment: Hello Geoff, There is one content type "Product display", but there are different product variation types and each product variation type has multiple fields with term references referring to taxonomy terms, also some fields are integers.

Comment: and 'product variation' is a content type? or what type of data structure - still not enough information, or at least there may be a terminology miscommunication...